# Sort array using recursion

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion

I have been trying to sort an array using recursion, but I am getting no output, can somebody help me with this, like why there is no output?

```
void sortarray(int arr[], int index, int key, int len){

    if (index == len-2){
    }
    else{
        if (key==len-1){
            key=0;
            sortarray(arr, index++, key, len );
        }
        else {
            if (arr[key] > arr[key+1]){
                swap(arr[key], arr[key+1]);
            }
         
            sortarray(arr, index, key++, len );


        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int arr[5] = {5,6,4,3,2};
    sortarray(arr, 0,0,5);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    }
}
```

Comment: most importantly, the increment operator is wrongly placed: instead of 
sortarray(arr, index++, key, len );
you have to write
sortarray(arr, ++index, key, len );
as you want to increment it BEFORE it is passed as an argument.

Comment: just use `+1` when you want to add one. There is really no reason to use pre or post increment here. `sortarray(arr, index+1, key, len );`

Comment: Well, I get screen full of '5' and then a segfault, so technically the issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: For correct sorting in bubblesort, your "len" should decrement instead of your index incrementing because the result of each key-loop is that the last element will be the maximum, so the end will be sorted, not the beginning.

Comment: There is no way this  works, btw, the first if condition is useless, the 2nd is the base case but can be replaced by just a return.  index is not used for anything. This means we just swap if necessary each pair of elements as we walk the array once.

Comment: If you want a recursive sort, lookup quicksort. It works by dividing your numbers into two halves, one half allow below some number (the "pivot") and one half above.  If you recursively call it on the two halves (you can leave the pivot out since it's sorted already)  at the end, your list will be sorted. It's a pretty common sort and was even supplied in the orignal C stdlib and there is also an example in Kernighan & Ritchie, the original C programming language book.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the segfault and simplified the code to make it more clear what it does.  Namely, walks the array once and swap the key with the next if it's larger.  This is not a valid sort algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sortarray(int arr[], int key, int len) {
    // base case
    if (key + 1 == len) return;

    // recursive case
    if (arr[key] > arr[key + 1]){
        swap(arr[key], arr[key + 1]);
    }
    sortarray(arr, key + 1, len );
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {5,6,4,3,2};
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
    sortarray(arr, 0, len);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the result is:

```
5  4  3  2  6
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some edits to your code and it works now (don't mind the printArr function, it's there just because cycles in main are ugly):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArr(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void sortarray(int arr[], int index, int key, int len)
{
    if (index < len)
    {
        if (key == len - 1) {
            key = 0;
            sortarray(arr, ++index, key, len);
        }
        else {
            if (arr[key] > arr[key + 1]) {
                swap(arr[key], arr[key + 1]);
            }
            sortarray(arr, index, ++key, len);


        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int arr[5] = { 5,6,4,3,2 };
    cout << "Before sort:" << endl;
    printArr(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
    sortarray(arr, 0, 0, 5);
    cout << "After sort:" << endl;
    printArr(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr));
    return 0;
}
```

So the first problem was missing iostream and std namespace.
Key changes in the algorithm itself were:

- change argument++ to ++argument
- change the first condition to (index < len)

As to why your code didn't work properly: the index missed the stopping condition and went over the value of len (thus the screen o' fives).

So this answers your question, but this algorithm you wrote breaks once there are two same values next to each other. There is a good reason we use cycles for sorting and unless recursion is the point, I would recommend abandoning it for this task.

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly-:

```
   void sortArr(int arr[],int index, int key, int len){
        // static int index = 0;
        // static int key = 0;
        if (index == len-1){
        }
        else{
            if (key==len-1){
                key=0;
                sortArr(arr,index+1,key,len );
            }
            else {
                if (arr[key] > arr[key+1]){
                    swap(arr[key], arr[key+1]);
                }
                sortArr(arr, index, key+1 ,len );
            }
        }
    }
int main(){
    int arr[5] = {5,6,4,3,2};
    sortarray(arr, 0, 5);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
2 3 4 5 6
```